# CSS :hover to show and hide HTML tags

Tags: html, css, hover

Is there any reason why the (.nav-element>a:hover) in the code below works, but (.nav-element>a:hover .nav-dropdown1) does not respond? I have tried multiple ways to activate it, but is there something wrong with the syntax on the rule which does not work? Here is all the code I've got so far:

```
.nav-contaier {
clear:left;
background-color: #3B3B3B; 
}

.element-container {
background-color:#3B3B3B;
height: 4em;
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
}

.element-container>ul {
width: 80%;
height: 100%;
margin: auto;
display: flex;
}

.nav-element {
text-align: center;
flex: 0 0 20%;
color: white;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
}

.nav-element>a {
line-height: 4em;
color: white;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
display: block;
}

.nav-element>a:hover {
background-color: black;

}

.nav-dropdown1 {
display: block;
opacity: 0;
width: 80%;
height: 100%;
margin-left: 10%;
position: absolute;
height: 2em;
z-index: 10;
background-color: blue;
}

.nav-element>a:hover .nav-dropdown1 {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 3em;
 }

 //HTML FROM HERE

    <div class="nav-contaier">
        <nav class="element-container">
            <ul>
                <li class="nav-element"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-element"><a href="index.html">Menu</a></li>
                <li class="nav-element"><a href="index.html">Lorem</a></li>
                <li class="nav-element"><a href="index.html">Ipsum</a></li>
                <li class="nav-element"><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="nav-dropdown1">

    </div>
```

Comment: The selector `.nav-element>a:hover .nav-dropdown1` does not match any of the elements in your HTML

Comment: Please - read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector - "There is currently no way to select the parent of an element in CSS."

Comment: hmm, so is there any way to write this:
.nav-element>a:hover <change the rules of> .nav-dropdown1 ?

Comment: I am not trying to access a parent. If you read the code I added, you'll see that the a-tag I am referring to is a child element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a reason for this.

Using `pseudo elements` like this will only work on actual `childs` of the `parent` element.

The only solution at this point would be using `JavaScript`.

Just a little sidenote, from your `HTML` structure it seems that you're trying to make a `nav-dropdown` for every `listitem`. A better way to do this would be

```
<ul>
  <li><a>Foo</a> 
    <ul>
      <li><a>Foo dropdown</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

There are tons of example on how to create a submenu, the advantages would be having a better `HTML` structure, and you'd actually be able to use the pseudo elements you've asked about.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you.